# I am getting error: ErrorException (E_WARNING) Creating default object from empty value check screenshot https://ibb.co/g9QTLqN

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am getting this error after i press save button in settings menu

Error Name:
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Creating default object from empty value

```
    //checkboxes settings (true/false)
    $checkboxesSettings = ['showPromoSlider', 'showMap', 'enablePushNotification', 'enablePushNotificationOrders', 'showGdpr', 'enableGoogleAnalytics', 'taxApplicable', 'enSOV', 'enSPU', 'enableFacebookLogin', 'enableGoogleLogin', 'enableDeliveryPin', 'hidePriceWhenZero', 'enableDeliveryGuyEarning', 'enPassResetEmail', 'showPercentageDiscount', 'showVegNonVegBadge', 'showFromNowDate', 'enDelChrRnd', 'expandAllItemMenu', 'smsRestaurantNotify', 'smsRestOrderValue', 'smsDeliveryNotify', 'smsOrderNotify', 'showOrderAddonsDelivery', 'showDeliveryFullAddressOnList', 'showUserInfoBeforePickup', 'recommendedLayoutV2', 'flatApartmentAddressRequired', 'showInActiveItemsToo', 'enGDMA', 'showPriceAndOrderCommentsDelivery', 'useSimpleSpinner', 'randomizeStores', 'showCouponDescriptionOnSuccess', 'stripeAcceptAliPay', 'stripeAcceptBitCoin', 'enIOSPWAPopup', 'mockSearchOnHomepage', 'stripeInlineCardCheckout', 'stripeAcceptIdealPayment', 'stripeAcceptFpxPayment', 'stripeCheckoutPostalCode', 'googleFullAddress'];

    foreach ($checkboxesSettings as $checkboxSetting) {
        $setting = Setting::where('key', $checkboxSetting)->first();
        if ($request->$checkboxSetting == 'true') {
            $setting->value = 'true';
            $setting->save();
        } else {
            $setting->value = 'false';
            $setting->save();
        }
    }

    if ($request->enDevMode == 'true') {
        $env = DotenvEditor::load();
        $env->setKey('APP_ENV', 'local');
        $env->setKey('APP_DEBUG', 'true');
        $env->save();
        $setting = Setting::where('key', 'enDevMode')->first();
        $setting->value = 'true';
        $setting->save();
    } else {
        $env = DotenvEditor::load();
        $env->setKey('APP_ENV', 'production');
        $env->setKey('APP_DEBUG', 'false');
        $env->save();
        $setting = Setting::where('key', 'enDevMode')->first();
        $setting->value = 'false';`enter code here`
        $setting->save();
```

Arguments
"Creating default object from empty value"

Comment: You might need to make sure `$setting` exists before you assign values to it.

Comment: It could be that your query fetching `$setting` returns null and you try to save it no matter what. You should check the query actually returned a row before your if else.

Comment: If `$setting = Setting::where('key', $checkboxSetting)->first();` does not find any results, then `$setting` will be null instead of being the object you're trying to update. Make sure that `$setting` is not null before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `firstOrFail()` instead of `first()`.

Sometimes you may wish to throw an exception if a model is not found. This is particularly useful in routes or controllers. The `findOrFail` and `firstOrFail` methods will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown:

```
$setting = Setting::findOrFail(1);

$setting = Setting::where('key', $checkboxSetting)->firstOrFail();
```